# How to display data from asyntask in another activity textviews?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have two activities.On Button click in the main activity corresponding Asynctask gets called(2 asynctask are there) and need to display those parsed Json datas in another activity's textviews(almost 10 textviews).How to do that?.

Comment: can you post your code?? have you overrided onPost methd in AsyncTask

Comment: @Jois I think I got what I was looking for from Alok Gupta's answer.Will update with my code if it doesnot work.Thanks btw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside onPostExecute() of your AsyncTask, you can create an Intent and put the data as extras in your intent and use that intent to redirect to your second activity, read the extras of your intent inside the onCreate() of second activity. The code will be something like...

```
onPostExecute(...){  //pass your data here
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
    myIntent.putExtra("MY_FIRST_TEXTVIEW_DATA","Value_of_first_tv_data");
    ....//Here you can put as many extras as you wish, your can also put an object with multiple values.
    ....
    startActivity(myIntent); //this will take to SecondAcitivity.
}
```

Once the control goes to SecondActivity, inside the onCreate()

```
....onCreate(...){
   ....
   setContentView(...);
   String firstTextViewData = getIntent().getStringExtra("MY_FIRST_TEXTVIEW_DATA");
//the value that you passed in myIntent with tag MY_FIRST_TEXTVIEW_DATA will be received inside firstTextViewData, now you can set it on a textview.
TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);
tv.setText(firstTextViewData);
 }
```

Hope you might have got some idea on how to do this. Let me know. Thanks

Comment: Thanks!..This is the answer I was looking for.Hope it works :)